# Stopping a while loop when a certain element of the list is reached

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

```
places= ["Home","In-n Out Burger", "John's house", "Santa Monica Pier", "Staples center",  "LA Dodgers stadium", "Home"]
def placesCount(places):
    multi_word = 0
    count = 0
    while True:
        place = places[count]
        if ' ' in place and place!='LA Dodgers stadium' **""" or anything that comes after LA dogers stadium"""** :
            multi_word += 1
        if '' in place and place!='LA Dodgers stadium' """ **or anything that comes after LA dogers stadium**""":
            count += 1
    print (count, "places to LA dodgers stadium"),  print (multi_word)
placesCount(places)
```

I basically want to know how I can stop the while-loop from adding to the list when it reaches a certain element of the list (`"LA Dodgers Stadium"`) in this case. It should not add anything after it reaches that element of the list.

Comment: Does this not work?

Comment: use `for place in places:` to loop over your places instead of the while-thingie; then you don't need any special handling for whitespace. Also why not a simple `len(places)`?

Answer (score 2):

Your code seem to work. Here is a slightly better version:

```
def placesCount(places):
    count = 0
    multi_word = 0
    for place in places:
        count += 1
        if ' ' in place:
            multi_word += 1
        if place == 'LA Dodgers stadium':
            break
    return count, multi_word
```

Or using [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import takewhile, ifilter

def placesCount(places):
    # Get list of places up to 'LA Dodgers stadium'
    places = list(takewhile(lambda x: x != 'LA Dodgers stadium', places))

    # And from those get a list of only those that include a space
    multi_places = list(ifilter(lambda x: ' ' in x, places))

    # Return their length
    return len(places), len(multi_places)
```

An example of how you could then use the function (that didn't change from your original example BTW, the function still behaves the same - accepts a list of places and returns a tuple with the two counts):

```
places = ["Home","In-n Out Burger", "John's house", "Santa Monica Pier", "Staples center",  "LA Dodgers stadium", "Home"]

# Run the function and save the results
count_all, count_with_spaces = placesCount(places)

# Print out the results
print "There are %d places" % count_all
print "There are %d places with spaces" % count_with_spaces
```

Comment: This is probably what the OP is after, +1

Comment: How can I print out the results?   print (placesCount) does not work

Answer (score 0):

```
place = None
while place != 'stop condition':
    do_stuff()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work just fine. I printed out the result of placesCount, which was (6, 5). Looks like this means the function hit 6 words, of which 5 were multi words. That fits with your data.

As Fredrik mentioned, using a for place in places loop would be a prettier way of accomplishing what you're trying to do.

Comment: How can I print out the results?   print (placesCount) does not work

Comment: If your function is returning any sort of data (like a number, list, etc), you should just be able to do print placesCount(places).